# respond_to does not redirect to new url

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, refresh

In all other methods it works fine with format.html, but in this one with format.js it updates the view but the visible url remains the same

```
 respond_to do |format|
 format.html { redirect_to some_path }
 format.js { redirect_to(:action => :index, :format => :js, :date => day}
 end
```

if I change the date the view won't refresh either:

```
 format.js { redirect_to(:action => :index, :format => :js, :date => params[:date])}
```

If i comment out format.html everything works the same way.

Do I need to update_attributes or somehow refresh the hidden_value?
Or add another redirect?
What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

format.js should return js code, so in this case, you will have to change to this

```
format.js { "window.location = 'your url';" }
```

Comment: +1 Nice! This is returning js to then load the new page into the browser.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work in Rails 4.1.8. I had to do: `format.js { render text: "window.location = 'your url';" }`